# Get Billing and Get Shipping Address in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Here I want a Billing and Shipping addresses according to `order_id`.
I receive a order data in my order object but it will give me just one record according to entity id.I want both address of order(billing and shipping).

Here is my code..

```
protected $order;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address $order
) {
    $this->order = $order;
  }

public function orderlist($orderid) {
    $order = $this->order->load($orderid);
    $a = $order->getData();
}
```

when I am printing $a it is giving me particular id record.I tried both getBillingAddress() and getShippingAddress(). it is giving me null value and blank page.
I not understanding the actual problem.

can any one help me?
thanks in advance..

Comment: print  get_class_methods($order). You will get number of methods to fetch data.

Answer (score 12):

I know, this was late, but just for use of other developers

```
$shippingaddress = $_order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
print_r($shippingaddress);
```

It will print all field inside array, then you will get the idea which field to retrive from it  for example

```
echo $_order->getShippingAddress()->getData("postcode");
```

to get postcode of shipping address

output of print_r($shippingaddress);

```
"entity_id": "164",
"parent_id": "180",
"customer_address_id": "6",
"quote_address_id": null,
"region_id": "60",
"customer_id": null,
"fax": null,
"region": "Virgin Islands",
"postcode": "111111",
"lastname": "Doe",
"street": "ca\nca",
"city": "ca",
"email": "johndoe@abc.com",
"telephone": "1512121212",
"country_id": "US",
"firstname": "John",
"address_type": "shipping",
"prefix": null,
"middlename": null,
"suffix": null,
"company": null,
"vat_id": null,
"vat_is_valid": null,
"vat_request_id": null,
"vat_request_date": null,
"vat_request_success": null
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like below

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order **/

protected $order;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
) {
    $this->order = $order;
  }

public function orderlist($orderid) {
    $order = $this->order->load($orderid);  // pass your order id here       
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData();
    $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i already use it. it will give me a blank page. ad  i mention in my question..

Comment: I updated my code, please use it and let me know if you have any issues

Comment: You should add `$` before before variable `shippingAddress` should  `$shippingAddress`

Comment: still get same issue.blank page.

Comment: This is probably because getShippingAddress() is not defined on the OrderInterface for the API.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this piece of code in the file:

```
<?php /** @var $_order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */ ?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php $billingAddress = $_order->getBillingAddress(); ?>
<?php $shippingAddress = $_order->getShippingAddress(); ?>
With $billingAddress now you can get address e.g:

<?php echo $billingAddress->getStreet() ?>
```

Comment: still get same issue.blank page.

Comment: The blank issue is due to `getStreet()` returns an array